# Exscript - Network Device Discovery/config gathering script (Python)

Tags: python, networking, discovery

I'm fairly new to python and am having difficulty with a script I am trying to use to gather config info from cisco network devices.

After a ping test to discover which devices are up, a file is created containing the responding IP's, and then parsed by an Exscript (python tool for SSH/telnet access) function.

The problem is that after the ping test is complete, and the file is created with the appropriate IP's, the script ends without beginning the quickstart or getdevinfo functions.

Any idea why this might be?

```
from Exscript.util.start import quickstart
from Exscript.util.interact import read_login
from Exscript.util.file import get_hosts_from_file
from Exscript import Account
import os

account = read_login()
hosts = open("hosts",'w')

for x in range(65,85):
    if os.system("ping -c 1 -W 2 172.16.200.%s" % x) == 0:
        print 'reachable'
        hosts.write("ssh://172.16.200.%s" % x + "\n")
    else:
        print 'unreachable'
hosts.close

def getdevinfo(job,host,conn):
    print 'connection started'
    conn.execute('show ver | i Ver')
    devtypeinfo = str(conn.response)
    forparse = devtypeinfo.split()
    for word in forparse:
        if word.lower() == "security":
            file = open("hostinfo - " + str(conn.host),'w')
            print "Device Type Detected: ASA"
            conn.send("enable\r")
            conn.app_authorize(account)
            conn.execute("show run hostname")
            file.write(conn.response)
            conn.execute("show int ip bri | excl unassigned")
            file.write(conn.response)
            conn.execute("show route")
            file.write(conn.response)
            conn.send("exit\r")
            conn.close()
            file.close()
        elif word.lower() == "ios":
            file = open("hostinfo - " + str(conn.host),'w')
            print "Device Type Detected: Router"
            conn.send("enable\r")
            conn.app_authorize(account)
            conn.execute("show run | i hostname")
            file.write(conn.response)
            conn.execute("show ip int bri | excl unassigned")
            file.write(conn.response)
            conn.execute("show ip route")
            file.write(conn.response)
            conn.execute("show cdp nei")
            file.write(conn.response)
            conn.send("exit\r")
            conn.close()
            file.close()

hosts2 = get_hosts_from_file('hosts')
quickstart(hosts2, getdevinfo, max_threads = 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone runs into something similar (which I kind of doubt because this script is so specific, maybe this wasn't the right place to post this) - the issue was that the quickstart function was being passed an empty list of hosts, so no connections were made.

To fix this, I skipped the get_hosts_from_file function and just added responding hosts to a list, and passed that list to the quickstart function.